# Cast_sender.js Chrome extension error in Genesis wordpress theme

Tags: google-chrome, error-handling, genesis

I recently started building a wordpress theme based on the Genesis Framework's Sample child theme. Everything is great and I have kept my requests to a minimum. The page in question loads  some font awesome icons, text, and there is one iFrame youtube video embedded on the page/post.

When running tests on Pingdom tools I am shown that I have 5 connection errors from the following: "cast_sender.js"

My question or concern is what this actually means: Does this negatively impact things such as a google page score or affect page loads even when it is zero file size and has no load indication?

Attached is a screen capture from pingdom.

[Screenshot from Pingdom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzZKZ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue that Google have yet to fix (or by the sounds of it, struggling). It's currently marked as "wontfix".

[Issue 309: error when chrome cast extension is not installed](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=309)

Not sure how it will affect page scores in the wider world, of course it's not a great issue to have either.